# ¿Como detectar error al pasar un puntero en vez de un bool?

Tags: c++

Recientemente cometí un error y pasé un puntero en vez de un `bool`, y el compilador no me avisó de nada. ¿Hay alguna forma de detectarlo?

Un ejemplo mínimo:

```
#include <iostream>

void funcion(bool variable);

void funcion(bool variable)
{
    std::cout << "En funcion variable= "<< variable <<" \n";
}

int main()
{
    int *b = NULL;

    funcion(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilado con:

```
g++ ejemplo.c++ -Wall -Wextra -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Wswitch-default -Wshadow -Wsign-promo
-Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wcast-align -Wdisabled-optimization -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-declarations
-Wmissing-include-dirs -Wnoexcept -Woverloaded-virtual -Wredundant-decls -Wstrict-null-sentinel
-Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wunused-macros -Wno-endif-labels -Wstrict-overflow=4 -Warray-bounds=2
-Wold-style-cast -Wconversion -Wunused -Wdouble-promotion -Wformat-overflow=2
-Wno-ignored-attributes -Wattributes -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wduplicated-branches
-Wduplicated-cond -Wtrampolines -Wfloat-equal -Wshadow=global -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations
-Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wdangling-else -Wfloat-conversion -Wlogical-op -Wredundant-decls
-Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wsuggest-attribute=cold
-Wsuggest-attribute=malloc -Wsuggest-attribute=const
```

Esto compila normalmente sin error ni advertencia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Al parecer no, ese es comportamiento *normal* del tipo [`bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions):

> *(Traducción)* 
> Los [valores puros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue) de tipo integral, coma flotante, enum plano y punteros, pueden ser convertidos a un valor puro de tipo bool.

Esto se puede comprobar:

```
enum Fruit { Apple,Pineapple };

void func(bool variable) { return; }

int main() {
    int* p = nullptr;
    int a = 10;
    float b = 3.14f;
    double c = 2.71;
    long double d = 1.66l;
    Fruit fruit = Apple;

    func(a);
    func(b);
    func(c);
    func(d);
    func(p);
    func(fruit);

    return 0;
}
```

Ninguna de estas llamadas a `func()` va a dar error o alerta alguna.  Por otro lado, si pasas el valor literal, te va a alertar que hay conversiones implícitas entre valores de coma flotante/`nullptr` a valores de tipo `bool`. Esto último no pasa con los valores integrales (`int` y `enum` que se castea implícitamente a `int`)

```
/*...*/    

    func(nullptr); //Alerta!
    func(10);
    func(3.14f); //Alerta!
    func(2.71); //Alerta!
    func(1.66l); //Alerta!
    func(Apple);
```

Si realmente quieres restringir un tipo de dato *incorrecto* a la función, puedes usar un [`enum class`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations). Estos evitan el casting implícito de sus valores a valores integrales. Obviamente tiene sus limitaciones, ya que no tiene las propiedades de un tipo de dato primitivo. Sin embargo, si puede ser útil para representar estados.

```
enum class Boolean { True,False };

void func(Boolean variable) { return; }

int main() {
    func(nullptr); //No compila
    func(Boolean::False); //Esto si compilaría
    
    return 0;
}
```

Al definir el parámetro de `func()` de esta manera, restringes a que solo se le pueden pasar como argumentos, valores que se definieron en el `enum` *Boolean* (en este caso `True` y `False`).

Answer (score 4):

Como te han dicho, la conversión entre tipos nativos y `bool` es algo comentado en el estándar. Además es una característica que **no se puede desactivar**

Por otro lado tenemos que la conversión únicamente se realizará cuando no se haya declarado una función cuya llamada sea directa (sin conversión).

Es decir, bastaría con declarar una plantilla que abarcase todas las posibles combinatorias y dejar dicha plantilla sin implementación. Si el compilador trata de usar una de esas funciones, al no encontrar implementación, arrojará un error en tiempo de enlazado:

```
#include <iostream>

void funcion(bool variable);

template <class T>
void funcion(T);

void funcion(bool variable)
{
    std::cout << "En funcion variable= "<< variable <<" \n";
}

int main()
{
    int *b = NULL;

    funcion(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Como podrás comprobar, el código no compilará hasta que `b` sea de tipo `bool`.

Finalmente, desde C++11 es posible *desactivar* algunas funciones, la ventaja de esta nueva característica es que en el código queda claro que la función no va a tener implementación porque nosotros deseamos que sea así, es decir, que no se trata de un despiste:

```
void funcion(bool variable);

template <class T>
void funcion(T) = delete;

void funcion(bool variable)
{
    std::cout << "En funcion variable= "<< variable <<" \n";
}

int main()
{
    int *b = NULL;

    funcion(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Otra ventaja de esta última solución es que el error se mostrará en tiempo de compilación, es decir, no tendremos que esperar a que el compilador haga casi todo el trabajo para enterarnos del error.

No son mecanismos perfectos (pues en ocasiones no te interesará desactivar todas las posibles conversiones), pero tratando con tipos nativos dudo que encuentres una solución mejor.